# Must be type not instance error when calling super()

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, singleton

My problem is that when i call **isSearchQueryValid()** and as a result **super()** i get this error:

```
must be type, not instance
```

I already found out that it has something to do with old/new class style but when i combine abstract methods, factories and singleton i am getting a little confused and don't know what is what anymore. Can you please point me the error?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty
from Singleton import *

class TorrentSiteFactory():    
    @staticmethod
    def Create(site):
        if site == "MySite": return MySite.GetInstance()

class Site(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def getSearchQueryLink(self): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def isSearchQueryValid(self, searchQuery, categories = None):
        '''Returns True if SearchQuery is ok, False when there are some errors. Additionally returns list of errors and warnings'''

        return True

@Singleton
class MySite(Site):
    def getList(self, searchQuery):
        searchLink = self.getSearchQueryLink(searchQuery)

    def getSearchQueryLink(self, searchQuery):
        searchQueryIsCorrect = self.isSearchQueryValid(searchQuery, self.Categories)
        if searchQueryIsCorrect: return "www.somelink.com"
        return None

    def isSearchQueryValid(self, searchQuery, categories):
        return super(MySite, self).isSearchQueryValid(searchQuery, categories)
```

And here is the Singleton:

```
class Singleton():
    def __init__(self, decorated):
        self._decorated = decorated

    def GetInstance(self):
        try:
            return self._instance
        except AttributeError:
            self._instance = self._decorated()
            return self._instance

    def __call__(self):
        raise TypeError('Singletons must be accessed through `Instance()`.')

    def __instancecheck__(self, inst):
        return isinstance(inst, self._decorated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Singleton` implementation is pretty broken. When you do

```
@Singleton
class MySite(Site):
    ...
```

`MySite` isn't the class you defined. It's an instance of `Singleton`. It doesn't have any of the methods of `MySite`, and `super(MySite, self)` can't find the MRO to look through. You'll have to change `Singleton` pretty heavily, if not rewrite it completely.

Also, `Singleton` and `TorrentSiteFactory` are classic classes, since you forgot to inherit from `object`.

Comment: Could you point me to any decent implementation of Singleton in Python? I tried googling but it's hard to decide which one is actually the best.